# Why my TransactionReceipt and TransactionHash always the same?

Tags: transactions

I setup my private node, able to deploy smart contract and makes RPC call.

However, I noticed that my TransactionReceipt and TransactionHash are always the same.

Are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: Do you have an example? The transaction hash should be different every time you create a new transaction.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication. What I mean was the transaction hash is different for different transaction. But within one single transaction, the TransactionReceipt and TransactionHash are the same.

Comment: For every transaction there's a transaction receipt that contains information of transaction execution. The transaction hash is used to link a transaction and its receipt, so the receipt has the transaction hash.